# How to Override onCreateDialog method in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am not able to override `onCreateDialog()` method in `Fragment`. But it is allowing me to override in `Activity`.

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    if (id == 999) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, myDateListener, year, month, day);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another method if you want to use the date and time picker dialog .
use https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker 
it is the material Dialog for date and time picker. you can use it in both activity and Fragment . for farment you can use if as

```
DatePickerDialog mDatepickerDialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(this,
            now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    );
```

if any problem or issue you can write in comments

Answer (score 5):

Use **DialogFragment**
            .In your fragment to extend DialogFragment class

```
public class Fragment extends DialogFragment {

  @Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

}
}
```

Comment: but its already extends Fragment ,it cannot extend another class

Comment: how to call this method?